# update table with if....then

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this table in my database:

```
GroupStandings
+--------+----------+--------------+--------+
| TeamID | GoalsFor | GoalsAgainst | Points |
+--------+----------+--------------+--------+
|      1 |        0 |            0 |      0 |
|      2 |        0 |            0 |      0 |
|      3 |        0 |            0 |      0 |
|      4 |        0 |            0 |      0 |
+--------+----------+--------------+--------+
```

I want to write a query that updates the points based on what I update my GoalsFor and GoalsAgainst as.
A very bad example for clarification:

```
update GroupStandings
set GoalsFor = 3, GoalsAgainst = 1,
    if GoalsFor>GoalsAgainst set points = 3
    else if GoalsFor=GoalsAgainst set points =1
    else set points = 0
where TeamID = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code and hope this helps you:

In this code, you can set GoalsFor and GoalsAgainst value in variables and then can compare in order to update points against each teamid.

```
Declare @GoalsFor int 
Declare @GoalsAgainst int

Set @GoalsFor = 3
Set @GoalsAgainst = 1 

Update GroupStandings Set GoalsFor = @GoalsFor, GoalsAgainst = @GoalsAgainst, 
Points = Case When @GoalsFor > @GoalsAgainst then 3 
              When @GoalsFor = @GoalsAgainst then 1 
              else 0 end
Where TeamId = 1

select * from GroupStandings
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if a working version of your sample query is all you're trying to achieve, but if so you want to use `CASE`:

```
update GroupStandings
set GoalsFor = 3
  , GoalsAgainst = 1
  , points = CASE WHEN GoalsFor>GoalsAgainst THEN 3
                  WHEN GoalsFor=GoalsAgainst THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END
where TeamID = 1
```

**Update:**

Based on all values being `0` to start, you could make `Points` a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN Points;
GO
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD Points AS (CASE WHEN GoalsFor>GoalsAgainst THEN 3
                                          WHEN GoalsFor=GoalsAgainst THEN 1
                                          ELSE 0
                                    END);
```

Or you could run 2 updates:

```
update GroupStandings
set GoalsFor = 3
  , GoalsAgainst = 1
where TeamID = 1
GO
update GroupStandings
set points = CASE WHEN GoalsFor>GoalsAgainst THEN 3
                  WHEN GoalsFor=GoalsAgainst THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END
where TeamID = 1
```

Or you could use variables to store your update values and use them in the single update:

```
DECLARE @GoalsFor INT = 3
       ,@GoalsAgainst INT = 1
update GroupStandings
set GoalsFor = @GoalsFor
  , GoalsAgainst = @GoalsAgainst
  , points = CASE WHEN @GoalsFor>@GoalsAgainst THEN 3
                  WHEN @GoalsFor=@GoalsAgainst THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END
where TeamID = 1
```

Comment: This almost works as I want it to. However, it checks for the CURRENT GoalsFor/GoalsAgainst (those already in the table). Meaning if I run your query, points will still be 0. If you understand.

Comment: @Christopher Makes sense, updated with some options.